# Dart2Js but readable

Tags: javascript, dart, flutter

Does someone knows if there is a way to compile a library which is written in Dart to JS. But in a way so that the generated code looks like handwritten or pretty close to it?

I would like to write a flutter app and share the business logic with the web-team. I don't want to force anyone to use Dart.

Right now it seems to me that the way javascript to dart works fine, but the way back dart to javascript doesn't works. I feel's like a one-way road. It would be awesome if some proof me wrong and can show that dart can interop with JS and backward, like Kotlin with Java

Thx for your answer ;D

Answer (score 2):

[DDC - Dart Dev Compiler](https://webdev.dartlang.org/tools/dartdevc) does that to some degree.

It's not intended for production use, but there are projects out there that use it that way anyway.